# class address is different with value address?

Tags: c++

```
class Test
{
    public:
        int m_value;
    public:
        void testA() { printf("A\n"); }
        void testB() { printf("B:%d", m_value); }
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    Test* test = NULL;
    test->testA();
    test->testB();
    return 0;
}
```

Why this program crashed in `test->testB()`, it should be **crashed** in `test->testA()`;

Comment: The code has *undefined behavior*.  There is no guarantee that the program will crash.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Calling a member function on a NULL pointer is cause for undefined behavior.

Your run time environment is dealing with the NULL pointer leniently. The call to `testA()` does not cause any problems since you are not accessing any member variables. The call to `testB()` crashes since you are trying to access a member variable when `this` is NULL.

Conceptually, a member function is mapped to a function that has the form:

```
mangled_testA(Test* this){ ... }
```

If you call such a function on a NULL pointer, the function gets called with the value of `this` set to NULL. If you don't access any member variables, you don't notice the error. If you access any member variables, you notice the error right away.

**P.S.** this behavior is not guaranteed by the language. This is what happens often.

Comment: you mean execute function testA() is OK while "this" pointer is NULL? why? "this" is NULL, how can it find testA() address?

Comment: thanks,i see. testA() address is not save in "Test", if I change testA() to virtual, it would crash in test->testA(), because "Test" class save the virtual function table at this time?

Comment: @Kid, If you change `testA()` to a virtual function and then call the function on a NULL pointer, your program will most likely crash.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this code and ran it in ideone [link to code](http://ideone.com/6nV7HM).
The issue is with the setting of `test =NULL` as the Object pointer is set to null.It means that the object is assigned a NULL value and will generally m_value will contain garbage.Depending on the compiler you are using, it will generate error(run time error as it is dynamic allocation). [reference1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3030829/c-is-it-possible-to-set-an-object-to-null)[reference2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6663230/whats-the-alternative-of-set-object-null-in-c-like-c-sharp)

Just remove the null and assign value to m_value your code will run fine.It is done so as to avoid memory leaks.